# Python HgApi and Mercurial: WindowsError

Tags: python, windows, mercurial

There is a problem with HgApi. When accessing a directory, an error occurs WindowsError. Look for examples of the treatment to the repository, but not found. The folder exists, I'm sure.

Code:

```
import hgapi

repo = hgapi.Repo(r"J:\any\odesk_pil")
repo.hg_init()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eugene/PycharmProjects/odesk/Mercurial3k/mercurial.py", line 6, in <module>
    repo.hg_init()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\hgapi-1.6.0-py3.2.egg\hgapi\hgapi.py", line 96, in hg_init
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\hgapi-1.6.0-py3.2.egg\hgapi\hgapi.py", line 92, in hg_command
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\hgapi-1.6.0-py3.2.egg\hgapi\hgapi.py", line 69, in command
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 744, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 977, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Comment: The error comes from `subprocess`, and `hgapi` uses the command line Mercurial to do things. Could it be that `hgapi` is not able to find the `hg` exec?

Comment: I understand that the error in the subprocess, but did not really understand what to do. Working with Mercurial recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the whole Mercurial + HgApi on a Windows XP virtual machine I've got here and it works without problems, which leads me to think that either:

- You haven't got Mercurial installed in your computer; or
- Mercurial (the `hg` program) is not on the `$PATH`

If you installed Mercurial using the official Windows package, the latter shouldn't be a problem, though.

Comment: Mercurial installed and registered in the Windows PATH. Only that it created a commit. At the command prompt, hg <command>, and python - no.

Comment: So, if you try `subprocess.call("hg")` on a Python shell, it works?

Comment: As I have already said no. Subprocess not see this command, then the command for it to run fine.

Comment: Well, we've got a problem then, because that's what `hgapi` is looking for. You claim that Mercurial is registered in the path, though. As I said, a cleanly installed Mercurial, using the binaries found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download) installs a `hg.exe` that can be run by `hgapi`

Comment: Tried multiple - result is negative. Command line sees them all, python - none.

Comment: Quick test. Is Mercurial's path in `os.environ['PATH']`? (It should, but...)

Comment: Registered C:\Program Files\Mercurial\.

Comment: `os.environ` holds a copy of the *process* environment. `os.environ['PATH']` tells you what System PATH is Python getting (the "Python PATH" for modules would be `sys.path`). Now, if Python is not getting the right PATH, that's something I don't know why, or how to help you fixing it, but should give you a hint. Also, you could try fixing it temporarily by adding Mercurial's path to `os.environ['PATH']`, because that modifies Python's environ (and it's subprocesses). It's not a permanent fix, but...

Comment: Added the directory to the PATH and worked! Thank you very much!